# How to set the grid-template-columns repeat() integer dynamically via a counter?

Tags: css, css-grid, css-counter

Not adding columns to the grid via `fill` or `fit`.

Incrementing/decrementing the `grid-template-columns` `repeat()` integer when `<app-panel>`s are dynamically added/removed to/from the DOM.

Something like this...

CSS:

```css
:root {
  --columns: column-sum;
}

app-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), minmax(100px, 1fr));
  /* other styles... */
}

app-column {
  counter-increment: column-sum;
  /* other styles... */
}
```

HTML: (custom tags)

```html
<app-container>
  <app-column></app-column>
  <app-column></app-column>
  <app-column></app-column>
  <app-column></app-column>
</app-container>
```

Rendered output should read:

```
app-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(100px; 1fr));
  /* other styles... */
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/dragontheory/pen/vYRLpgM)

Why doesn't that work?

Comment: you cannot do this with counter but what are you looking to achieve?

Comment: @temani-afif Customer uses Grid exclusively. Grid-template-columns repeat() must be an integer (not auto, fill, or fit). Trying to figure out how to leverage CSS's unique "liveness" to update the integer in real time. Maybe att()? Open to ideas. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: it's seems you need to use `grid-auto-flow:column`. This will force a column layout and it will adjust whataver the number of elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little JS snippet to set columns based on the amount of children elements. Also consider using flex for this

```js
const containers = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('container'));

containers.forEach( container => container.style.cssText = `--columns: ${container.children.length}` );
```

```css
/* DISPLAY GRID */
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( var(--columns), 1fr );
}

/* DISPLAY FLEX */
.container2 { display: flex }
.container2 > div { flex: 1 1 auto }


/* COMMON STYLES FOR EXAMPLE PURPOSES */
.container, .container2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  gap: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em
}
.container > div, .container2 > div { border: 1px solid red }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Grid Col 1</div>
  <div>Grid Col 2</div>
  <div>Grid Col 3</div>
  <div>Grid Col 4</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>Grid Col 1</div>
  <div>Grid Col 2</div>
  <div>Grid Col 3</div>
  <div>Grid Col 4</div>
  <div>Grid Col 5</div>
  <div>Grid Col 6</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>Grid Col 1</div>
  <div>Grid Col 2</div>
  <div>Grid Col 3</div>
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <div>Flex Col 1</div>
  <div>Flex Col 2</div>
  <div>Flex Col 3</div>
  <div>Flex Col 4</div>
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <div>Flex Col 1</div>
  <div>Flex Col 2</div>
  <div>Flex Col 3</div>
  <div>Flex Col 4</div>
  <div>Flex Col 5</div>
  <div>Flex Col 6</div>
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <div>Flex Col 1</div>
  <div>Flex Col 2</div>
  <div>Flex Col 3</div>
</div>
```